# How to pass variables to an Ansible playbook in an Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, ansible-2.x, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to pass a variable named "required_location" to my ansible playbook in Azure pipeline. I tried `extraVars` and `$[variables.variable]` methods. But it didn't work.

```yaml
trigger:
 - none

parameters:
  - name: NASlocation
    displayName: location
    default: A
    type: string
    values:
      - A
      - B

variables:
  - group: Xyz.Coesd.VariableGroup.GlobalVars
  - group: nas
  - name: required_location
    value: ${{ parameters.NASlocation}}


resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipetemplates
      type: git
      name: XYZ0002357/pita-pipeline-templates
      ref: 'refs/heads/iib-changes'


stages:
- stage: COTS_CI
  jobs:
  - template: flows/cos-ci.yml@pipetemplates


- stage: CD_DEV
  dependsOn:
  - COTS_CI
  jobs:
  - template: flows/cos-at.yml@pipetemplates
    parameters:
      deployment_environment: 'DEV'
      target_platform: 'XYZ'
      vault_password: $(ansible_vault_password)
      playbook_name: 'create_nfs'
      inputs:
        required_location: $[variables.required_location]
```

The error that I get in the execution of playbooks is

> 'required_location' is undefined

In my Ansible playbook named `create_nfs`, I am expecting to capture the value of a variable named `required_location` as `A` or `B` using Jinja template `{{ required_location }}`.

Comment: I don't know what `flows/cos-at.yml` contains but to pass the variable you need to do in this way: `$(required_location)`

Comment: I did that way also. But this variable is not getting recognized in the playbook "create_nfs" while I execute the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the stage>job>parameter, I got a way to call the variable using parameter'job_extra_vars'

job_extra_vars: '{"final_location": $(required_location)}'

Then I am able to get final_location as variable with the required value in it during the execution.