# Use library from Azure Pipelines to replace Ansible variables

Tags: ansible, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure key vault linked to a library on Azure DevOps named 'AzureKeyVault'.
I set a key/value (vmdp: for azure virtual machine password) on the vault.
Then I activate this new secret in the library.

This secret is used to connect my Ansible VM to the Windows VM using WinRM.
In my configuration file for Ansible, I have this:

```
ansible_user: administrateur
ansible_password: "{{ VMDP }}"
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

I have to call the secret on the pipeline below:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - main

pool:
  name: 'dev'

stages:
- stage: Ansible
  displayName: Ansible
  jobs:
  - job: Ansible
    displayName: Ansible
    variables:  
      - group: 'AzureKeyVault'
    steps:
    - bash: ansible-playbook playbook_windows.yml
      displayName: 'Run Ansible Playbook for Windows'
      env:
        VMDP: $(vmdp)
```

After running the pipeline, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [win01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'password' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'VMDP' is undefined. 'VMDP' is undefined. 'VMDP' is undefined. 'VMDP' is undefined"}
```

I saw this post [How to pass variables to an Ansible playbook in an Azure YAML pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709124/how-to-pass-variables-to-an-ansible-playbook-in-an-azure-yaml-pipeline)
I don't really understand where to put it and if I really need it
I am a beginner when it comes to pipelines.

Does anyone have an idea ?